# Svyglm in package survey in R not returning Std Errors

Tags: r, survey, standard-error

I'd really appreciate some assistance with this. I'd like to estimate coefficients and 95% CI for a glm that is applied to a household survey with 2 levels (defined by dd and hh.num1). I've only recently come across the package *survey*.

I've been following the examples within vignette for 1) setting up a dataset to consider the sampling methods - using *svydesign* 2) setting up a glm using the command *svyglm*. For the example datasets:

```
library(survey)data(api)head(apiclus1)dclus1 <- svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1)logitmodel <-svyglm(I(sch.wide=="Yes")~awards+comp.imp+enroll+target+hsg+pct.resp+mobility+ell+meals, design=dclus1, family=quasibinomial())summary(logitmodel)
```

Adding lots of variables seems OK so I'm confident that the package is working with a good dataset.

When I do the same to my dataset, the std errors return with "Inf" if 3 or 4 variables are added in and I can't figure out why. It seems as though it's more common with factors. I'm sorry that I haven't been able to replicate the error with the other examples, but the dataset could be [downloaded here](https://github.com/kath-o-reilly/pakistan-routinevacc).

So using this dataset:

```
load("balo2_7March17.Rdat")  
dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dd+hh.num1, weights=~chweight, data = balo2)  
glm1 <- svyglm(out.penta ~ factor(MN18c) + windex5 + age.y, 
          design=dclus1, family=quasibinomial())  
summary(glm1)
```

If MN18c is numeric then the std errors are produced, if it's a factor (and it should be) the stnd errors are Inf. Short of knowing what else to do I'll need to try the analysis in STATA. I saw some commentary that errors may occur if applied to a "bad" dataset, but what comprises "bad"?

Comment: hi, `load("balo2_7March17.Rdat")  
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘balo2_7March17.Rdat’ has magic number ''
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated `

Comment: Hi @Kath O'Reilly were you able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have zero residual degrees of freedom in your model.  The residual df is the design df (the number of PSUs minus the number of strata) minus the number of predictors, which can easily get negative when you have two large clusters per stratum.  This definition of residual df is probably conservative, but it's not a straightforward question.

```
>  degf(dclus1)
[1] 5
> glm1$df.resid
[1] 0
```

You can extract the standard errors with

```
> SE(glm1)
   (Intercept) factor(MN18c)2 factor(MN18c)3 factor(MN18c)4        windex5 
     0.5461374      0.4655331      0.2805168      0.3718879      0.1376936 
         age.y 
     0.1638210
```

and if you are willing to use a different residual degrees of freedom, you can specify that to `summary` and get $p$-values.  In particular, if none of your covariates are at the cluster level, there is a reasonable argument that the regression doesn't use up degrees of freedom and so for one parameter at a time you can do

```
> summary(glm1, df=degf(dclus1))

Call:
svyglm(formula = out.penta ~ factor(MN18c) + windex5 + age.y, 
    design = dclus1, family = quasibinomial())

Survey design:
svydesign(id = ~dd + hh.num1, weights = ~chweight, data = balo2)

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     -3.0848     0.5461  -5.648  0.00241 **
factor(MN18c)2  -0.1183     0.4655  -0.254  0.80957   
factor(MN18c)3  -0.4908     0.2805  -1.750  0.14059   
factor(MN18c)4  -0.6137     0.3719  -1.650  0.15981   
windex5          0.2556     0.1377   1.856  0.12256   
age.y            0.9934     0.1638   6.064  0.00176 **
```

Combining parameters (eg to test the three coefficients making up `MN18c`) is more problematic, and I think you at least need `df=degf(clus1)-3+1`.

In the forthcoming version 4.1 the package will report standard errors in this situation (but not $p$-values unless a different `df=` is specified)